# Drools "join" like SQL in collect

Tags: java, drools

So I something like SQL join possible in drools. I have ItemFact collection (1,2,3,...), each item may be used in different baskets. I have CanUseItemInBasket facts, that represents if item can be used in basket or no

I have tried this

```
rule "xxx"
    when
        $beers : ArrayList() from collect( ItemFact(id == $orderItemId )
                             from collect(CanUseItemInBasket($itemId: orderItemId, basketId == 5)))
    then
    ...
end
```

or this

```
rule "xxx"
    when
        $beers : ArrayList() from collect( ItemFact(id == $orderItemId ), CanUseItemInBasket($itemId: orderItemId, basketId == 5))
    then
    ...
end
```

but this approaches not work. I know I add field `basketId` to ItemFact and add multiple ItemFacts with the same `id` and different `basketIds`, but in this approach ItemFact is "cloned" in working memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To collect the `ItemFact` instances whose `id` is in the selected `CanUseItemInBasket` instances you can use `accumulate`:

```
rule "Collect beers"
when
    $beers : List() from accumulate(CanUseItemInBasket($itemId: orderItemId, basketId == 5) and
                                    $item: ItemFact(id == $itemId);
                                    collectList($item))
then
    System.out.println($beers);
end
```

The [v6.x language reference](https://docs.drools.org/6.5.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#d0e11001) says:

> The Conditional Element `accumulate` is a more flexible and powerful
> form of `collect`, in the sense that it can be used to do what
> `collect` does and also achieve results that the CE `collect` is not
> capable of achieving.

A similar note is in [v7.x](https://docs.drools.org/7.74.1.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#:%7E:text=all%20parents.%0Aend-,accumulate,-Use%20this%20to), and [v8.x](https://docs.drools.org/8.44.0.Final/drools-docs/drools/language-reference/index.html#_legacy_drl_rule_condition_elements) lists `collect` among obsolete keywords.

Comment: Why are we using a 7 year old language reference?

Comment: Here's the current language reference which makes no reference to `collect` since it's, you know, deprecated: https://docs.drools.org/8.44.0.Final/drools-docs/drools/language-reference/index.html#accumulate

Comment: Also your syntax is wrong, the pattern for accumulate is `accumulate( SOURCE_PATTERN; FUNCTION(S) )` -- semi colon to separate the source patterns from collectList. Should be `accumulate( CanUseItemInBasket(...), $item: ItemFact(...) ; collectList($item))`

Comment: This solution works as expected, thank you!

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, yes, my link is old but I guess that the OP is using an old version of Drools (or, at least, old syntax without OOPath).  Probably the best choice for the needs of the OP is the latest v7.x (3 months old), but its doc hasn't an anchor for `accumulate`.  However I improved the links and the syntax even if the compiler in this case accepts a comma too as "[alternate syntax](https://docs.drools.org/8.44.0.Final/drools-docs/drools/language-reference/index.html#:~:text=accumulate%20alternate%20syntax)".  Thanks for your notes.

Comment: Drools 8.x still supports non-oopath; there's nothing really in the OP that really ties them to any specific Drools version >= 5.0.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, yes, I simply wanted to avoid a doc that contains examples with OOPath.

Comment: It is pretty awful. The 7.x docs, then, would probably be OK -- unfortunately the 6.x ones have a whole lot of stuff that's just no longer relevant because they were in that weird transition period to Kie. And the documentation got a lot better in the 7.x series.